# can't get the mockito to mock a public method of a public class

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to mock the `getMeasureAggregator()` of  ResultSetRow object - I don't seem to succeed. I am very new in writing mockito unit test.

I want the `BuilSQL.formatMeasuer()` goes to `case 2`: so what I have decided to do was mocking row.getMeasureAggregator.

Here is my BuildSQL class:

```
public class SQLBuilder {

    public static String buildSQL(JsonObject requestData, JsonObject queryInfo) throws AcquisitionException {
        JsonArray jArray = queryInfo.get("columns").getAsJsonArray();
        Set<String> columns = new HashSet<>(jArray.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.size(); i++) {
            columns.add(jArray.get(i).getAsString());
        }
        List<ResultSetRow> selectedRows = new ArrayList<>();
        List<ResultSetRow> retrievedRows = null;
        retrievedRows = MetaDataProvider.executeMetadataRequest(queryInfo, requestData); // this method returns a collection of RetrievedResultSetRow

        for (ResultSetRow retrievedRow: retrievedRows) {
            if (//some condition evaluates to true) {
                selectedRows.add(retrievedRow);
            }
        }

        String sql = "";
        String select = "SELECT ";
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.size(); i++) {
            ResultSetRow row = selectedRows.get(i);
            select += formatMeasure(row.getMeatureName(), row.getMeasureAggregator());            
        }
        select = select.substring(0, select.length() - 1);
        return sql;
    }

    private static String formatMeasure(String measureName, int measureAggregator) {
        switch(measureAggregator) {
            case 1:
                return "sum(\"" + measureName + "\")" + " AS \"" + measureName + "\",";
            case 2:
                return "COUNT(\"" + measureName + "\")" + " AS \"" + measureName + "\",";
        return measureName;
    }
}
```

here is my ResultSetRow class:

```
public class ResultSetRow {
    private final int iRow;
    private final int measureAggregator;

    public ResultSetRow(JsonObject dimensionMetadata) {
        this.iRow = dimensionMetadata.get("ROW").getAsInt();
        this.measureAggregator = dimensionMetadata.get("MEASURE_AGGR").getAsInt();
    }

    public int getMeasureAggregator() {
        return measureAggregator;
    }

}
```

here is how I am mocking

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ HanaClientRequestUtils.class, RetrievedResultSetRow.class })

public class HanaSQLBuilderTest {
    private ResultSetRow resultSetRow;
    private requestData;
    private queryInfo



    @Test
    public void formatMeatureExecuteCase2() throws Exception{
        resultSetRow = Mockito.mock(ResultSetRow.class);
        PowerMockito.when(resultSetRow.getMeasureAggregator()).thenReturn(2);
        String querySQL = HanaSQLBuilder.buildSQL(requestData, queryInfo);
        System.out.println(querySQL);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure why `row.getMeasureAggregator()` does not return 2?

Comment: You need to retrieve in `MetaDataProvider.executeMetadataRequest(...)` method the exact object what You mock in Your test. Otherwise the ResultSetRow instances are not mocked by Mockito.

Comment: What You can do is to mock also `MetaDataProvider.executeMetadataRequest` so it returns a list of your mocked `ResultSetRow`s. But because this method is static, Mockito can have problems mocking it (PowerMock can mock static methods as I know, but please check it).

Comment: @zolv: thanks for ur reply. I know we can mock static method using powerMockito. can u refer me to some example?

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/using-powermock-mock-static

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to my comments above (I am coding by hand, forgive me some mistakes).
You can try with adding a `retrievedRows` as a parameter in Your buildSQL method:

```
public static String buildSQL(
    JsonObject requestData,
    JsonObject queryInfo,
    List<ResultSetRow> retrievedRows) throws AcquisitionException {
      // ... rest of Your code adopted to new parameter
```

}

And then provide Your `retrievedRows` filled with mocks

```
@Test
public void formatMeatureExecuteCase2() throws Exception{
    resultSetRow = Mockito.mock(ResultSetRow.class);
    PowerMockito.when(resultSetRow.getMeasureAggregator()).thenReturn(2);

    List<ResultSetRow> retrievedRowsMock = new ArrayList<>(1);
    retrievedRowsMock.add(resultSetRow);

    String querySQL = HanaSQLBuilder.buildSQL(requestData, queryInfo, retrievedRowsMock);
    System.out.println(querySQL);
    }
}
```

I hope it will guide You to solution.